# What happens behind the scene of PHPs foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, php-7.1

Experiments in PHP 7.1 (docker image nanoninja/php-fpm:7.1)

In next piece of code everything clear:

```
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3];

foreach ($arr1 as &$value) {
    $value *= 2;
}
```

We have array `$arr1` and multiply all values by 2. Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
  [2]=>
  &int(6)
}
```

But what happens in this statement:

```
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3];

foreach ($arr2 = $arr1 as &$value) {
    $value *= 2;
}
```

Result of both arrays `$arr1` and `$arr2` will unchangeable:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Why is it happens? I know that in PHP > 7 `foreach` works with copy of array but with copy of which array it works in this case `$arr1` or `$arr2`. And why `&` don't work?

Comment: Can you do an inline declaration like that and pass a variable as a reference in the same spot? Which would the for each be using in that situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-php-foreach-actually-work)

Comment: `foreach ($arr2 = $arr1 as ...` is equivalent to `foreach (function() as ...` - in both cases iterator loops over temporary array which is discarded after operation

Answer (score 6):

`foreach` only works with a copy of the array in the normal by-value mode, not in by-reference mode. So that change in PHP 7 is not relevant to this code.

But in your second code block, you're not using a variable as the array to iterate over, so there's nothing to make a reference to. Instead, you have an expression, and the value of the expression is a copy of the array. It's essentially equivalent to doing:

```
$temp = $array1 = $array2;
foreach ($temp as &$value) {
    $value *= 2;
}
```

This will update `$temp`, but not `$array1` or `$array2`.